# ScheduledExecutorService for tasks that persist after an exception

Tags: java, task, scheduling, scheduledexecutorservice

The documentation of the `scheduleAtFixedRate()` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` methods of the `Java` [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), says that, for any scheduled task, "If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.".

Is there any way of having the same functionality with these two methods, but persist even after an exception in the task (other than manually suppressing that exception)?

Comment: Why must you use these 2 methods?

Comment: They are already used in the code and cannot easily be changed. Besides, why not? They are not deprecated. If you have any alternative suggestion, please be more specific.

Comment: Well because you have the problem that once one execution breaks, everything else does. Is this a spring application?

Comment: No, just native Java.

Answer (score 0):

Not just using those methods, but you can pretty easily make your own scheduled executor that effectively sidesteps that behavior. I haven't tried to compile this, but as a first stab.

```java
public final class KeepOnChuggingExecutor implements ScheduledExecutorService {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    

    public KeepOnChuggingExecutor(ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService) {
        this.scheduledExecutorService = scheduledExecutorService;
    }

    // Handle any exceptions in tasks
    private Runnable wrapRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Log it if you want to
            }
        };
    }

    private Callable<V> wrapCallable(Callable<V> callable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Log it if you want to
            }
        };
    }

    // And then for every interface method on scheduled executor, wrap the
    // given task so that exceptions don't bubble up.
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule​(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
        return this.scheduledExecutorService.schedule(
            this.wrapRunnable(command),
            delay, 
            unit
        );
    }

    @Override
    public <V> ScheduledFuture<V> schedule​(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
        return this.scheduledExecutorService.schedule(
            this.wrapCallable(callable),
            delay,
            unit
        );
    }


    // And so on for all the scheduled methods. Then the rest of the methods in
    // Executor you can just delegate to the service this class wraps.

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return this.scheduledExecutorService.isTerminated();
    }
    // ...

}
```

So the general solution here is the "composition" pattern. Its verbose, and you do repeat yourself, but you both can't subclass an arbitrary executor to avoid the duplication and probably don't want to (lest ye fall to the fates of all those who look upon inheritance and weep)

You still need to suppress the exception, but moving that work away from your definition of a task has some benefits.